# No member named in class

Tags: c++

So here's my code

MyClass.h:

```
namespace ns{
  template <typename A, typename B>
  class MyClass{
    struct MyStruct1;
    struct MyStruct2;

    struct MyStruct1{
      /*not important here*/
    };

    struct MyStruct2{
      MyStruct2(std::weak_ptr<MyStruct1> i1, std::weak_ptr<MyStruct1> i2, B i3):d1{i1}, d2{i2}, d3{i3} {};
      std::weak_ptr<MyStruct1> d1;
      std::weak_ptr<MyStruct1> d2;
      B d3;
    };
    //Compare MyStruct2
    static bool compareMyStruct2(std::weak_ptr<MyStruct2>& e1, std::weak_ptr<MyStruct2>& e2);
  };

  template<typename A, typename B>
  bool MyClass<A, B>::compareMyStruct2(std::weak_ptr<MyStruct2>& e1, std::weak_ptr<MyStruct2>& e2){
    return (e1->d3 < e2->d3);
  }
}
```

When I build, the compiler is telling me that

```
No member named 'd3' in 'std::_1::weak_ptr<ns::MyClass::MyStruct2'
```

I have no idea why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Too many semi-colons missing everywhere.

Comment: ^^ To extend on the above, in c++ you need to put a semicolon (`;`)  after `class`/ `struct` declarations. _@SuperMurloc_ Your question doesn't look useful in the long term, delete it please.

Comment: Also, within implementation of compareMyStruct2 `MyClass` should be `MyClass<A,B>` and `MyStruct2`, nested class, can't be used outside `MyClass` without `MyClass<A,B>::`

Comment: And parameters are passed by value (declaration) vs reference (implementation). `const` reference will be better.

Comment: I use an IDE to write the actual code but it's too long to read so this is a dummy. Sorry for the missing semi-colons, I've fixed them as well as the pass by reference problem in the example. I'm still getting the same error message from my IDE :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to invoke `operator->` on `weak_ptr`, which does not have it.

`weak_ptr` is not really a pointer-like object. It cannot be dereferenced. What you can do, is try to construct a `shared_ptr` from it: if `weak_ptr` has expired, you will get an exception, otherwise you will get valid `shared_ptr`, which is a pointer-like object.

```
return (std::shared_ptr<MyStruct2>(e1)->d3 < std::shared_ptr<MyStruct2>(e2)->d3);
```

Easier way to do so is to call `.lock()` on `weak_ptr`:

```
return (e1.lock()->d3 < e2.lock()->d3);
```

But you must know that `.lock()` returns empty `shared_ptr` when called on expired `weak_ptr`. You need to either test that resulting pointers are not equal to `nullptr`, ensure that they did not expire beforehand or use `shared_ptr` constructor from `weak_ptr`.

Of course, if you need something more complex, you should store created `shared_ptr` and not create it each time you want to access object:

```
auto p1 = e1.lock();
auto p2 = e2.lock();
if (not (p1 && p2))
    throw /*expired pointers*/;
// Do stuff here
// return p1->d3 < p2->d3;
```